# How to sort by date in explore view?

Tags: google-analytics

The only way I found to show a day to day report of certain events is in explore view. In reports, for some reason I can't create segment. Segment seems to be a explore only thing.

So in explore, I was able to create a segment and then show events day by day.

But for some weird reason, the date is not sorted by day. It's seems random. 24->22->28.

How to fix?

[image]